# I am getting error when using usecontext in react js that says i didn't not export a function that explicitly exported

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

hello so was just studying react hooks and got stuck on useContext i think my code is ok but it showing odd error that is saying

> Attempted import error: 'ThemeProvider' is not exported from './ThemeProvider' (imported as 'ThemeProvider').
> WARNING in [eslint]
> src\Hooks\Context\ThemeContext.js
> Line 7:14:  'ToggleTheme' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

> ERROR in ./src/Hooks/Context/UseContext.js 11:23-36
> export 'ThemeProvider' (imported as 'ThemeProvider') was not found in './ThemeProvider' (possible exports: default, useThemeContext, useThemeUpdate)

> webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

here is my code the below are code from 4 files one is App.js that is just in the src and the other are found in file called context, the context file is in the src
what am i doing wrong ? i clearly exported my themeprovider  ?

```
import Context from "./Hooks/Context/UseContext"
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Context/>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in the UseContext.js i have

```
import React from 'react'
import FunctionContext from './FunctionContext'
// import ClassContext from "./ClassContext"
import {ThemeProvider} from "./ThemeProvider"
// export const ThemeContext = React.createContext()

export default function UseContexTry(){
<ThemeProvider>
    <FunctionContext/>
</ThemeProvider>
}
```

in the ThemeProvider.js

```
import React, {useState, useContext } from 'react'


const ThemeContext = React.createContext()
const ThemeUpdate =React.createContext()

export function useThemeContext(){
    return useContext(ThemeContext)
}
export function useThemeUpdate(){
    return useContext(ThemeUpdate)
}


export default function ThemeProvider({children}) {

    const [darkTheme , setDarkTheme]= useState(false)

    function ToggleTheme(){
        setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme=>!prevDarkTheme)
    }

    return(
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={darkTheme}>
    <ThemeUpdate.Provider value={ToggleTheme}>
        {children}
    </ThemeUpdate.Provider>
       
    </ThemeContext.Provider>)
 }
```

in the FunctionContext.js file i have

```
import React from 'react'
import {useThemeContext, useThemeUpdate} from './ThemeProvider'

export default function FunctionContext() {
    // const darkTheme= useContext(ThemeContext)
    const darkTheme= useThemeContext()
    const ToggleTheme = useThemeUpdate()





    const ThemeStyle={
        backgroundColor:darkTheme ? '#333':'#ccc',
        color: darkTheme ?  '#ccc': '#333',
        padding:'2rem',
        margin: '2rem'
    }
    return(
        <>
         <button onClick={ToggleTheme}>themem toggler</button>
        <div style={ThemeStyle}>
            function use this

        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Typo, you should use named export like `export function ThemeProvider() {}`

Comment: @LinDu so the error is gone on the terminal but the browser is showing nothing when i check console on the browser it shows no error. Dont i need to add default

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://codesandbox.io/?